# Why do I have different password for my laptop's windows 10 (signed in with MS) as compared to my MS email password?

Tags: windows-10, login, microsoft-account

I have Windows 10 installed in my haier PC. Although I am logged in with Microsoft account, it has a different password than my Microsoft email's password. **(Note that I am not signed in with local account)** Why is that?

I want to set my laptop's password synchronized with Microsoft account so that if I ever forget the password, I can log into my already signed-in email (thanks to saved passwords) and change my laptop password.

[image: My Account screenshot]
[image: Email and app accounts screenshot]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Accounts within Settings?  Be sure to remove your email address and name, I just want to see an indication, the account is linked to your Microsoft account.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes added in my post. Please have a look

Comment: Based on your screenshot, you actually are using a local account, and your Microsoft Account is otherwise linked to the approrpriate applications.  If you were signed in a link account, there would be a link at the bottom of the page, to create a local account.  **Your screenshot does not have that link.**  What edition of Windows 10 are you using?  What version (build) of Windows 10 do you have installed?